# Finding all AJAX entrypoints

Tags: tools, ajax, attack-vector

Is there any tool to (automatically) find all backend JavaScript entrypoints within a site?

I have to check a site for vulnerabilities in the backend code that validates AJAX parameters and I would like to first generate a list of all addresses that receive AJAX calls.

I am almost certain this can be done with a high probability, as the most common ways to have AJAX are fairly known: XmlHttpRequest, jQuery and other JS libraries; and these are all detectable. So if all other fails, I will probably write something like this myself.

But I would prefer to use an established tool if there is such, since it would probably be both less buggy, and easier.

So, does such a thing exist?

Comment: XmlHttpRequest is'nt the only *ajax* way!

Comment: @F.Hauri I do not claim it is, merely that all of them *should* be easily detectable.

Comment: From simpe `A href=, target=hidden` to `websocket`... You've better to trace connexion (tcp traffic or with a browser tool like `firebug`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend reading ["Crawling Ajax-driven Web 2.0 Applications"](http://www.net-security.org/dl/articles/Crawling_Ajax_driven_Web_2.0.pdf). The paper discusses different crawling techniques for Ajax-driven Web application. Through Crawling we try to collect all possible resources from the server for vulnerability assessment. But this is not possible with traditional protocol driven approach for Ajax driven web application. Since traditional approach crawler sends HTTP request and interpret responses but  for Ajax-driven web application we require event driven crawling. You can work with Ajax based crawler such as [Crawljax](http://crawljax.com/)

Comment: Ali fix link for http://crawljax.com/ :)
Also : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rYAO94GnBlY